# How to stream tweets from a specified user (only stream when the tweet is published by this user) using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, stream, tweepy

I tried the following codes:

```py
    class MyListener(StreamListener):
        def on_data(self, data):
            print(data)
            return True

    listener = MyListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(config.ACCESS_TOKEN, config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(follow=['<user_id>'])  # assume this user is a celebrity
```

What I got when running this code, is many spam-tweets or retweets by other users. (assume this `<user id>` is a celebrity, who has millions of followers. The followers are sharing the tweets all the time)

---

But I want to stream the original tweets published `only` by this specific `<user id>`. How can I implement this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters) says that using the `follow` parameter you get :

- Tweets created by the user.
- Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
- Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
- Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
- Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).

So you just have to skip tweets not posted by the specified user :

```
def on_status(self, status):
    if status.user.id_str != '<user_id>':
        return
    print(status.text)
```

Comment: This would be my chosen solution, as well - drop anything that isn't generated by the specific account.